# Is there a way to set up Amazon Code Whisperer in VS Code so that it only displays with a certain key command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-codewhisperer

CodeWhisperer often offers up some code too quickly and interrupts my flow.
It would be great to say "now" with a keyboard command to ask it to go into action.

Possible?

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this, bumping for visibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option+C (MacOS) or Alt+C (Windows) will manually trigger CodeWhisperer any time. You can go into the Developer Tools panel of the AWS Toolkit and click Pause Auto-Suggestions and then only manually trigger it.

Comment: [Here are instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codewhisperer/latest/userguide/toggling-suggestions.html) on accessing the AWS Toolkit's Developer Tools panel and pausing auto-suggestions.  (I wasn't clear on this point and ended up opening VS Code's general **Help > Toggle Developer Tools** view.)

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do this is by using VSCode Keyboard short cuts. This would allow you to choose a set of keys that would toggle (enable/disable) CodeWhisperer from running.

From PREFERENCES>KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS in VSCode, search for "codewhisper" and this will highlight all the options.

I selected "aws.codewhisperer.enableCodeSuggestions" and then selected a key convenient to me. Now when I want to enable/disable, I can do this using that key combination.

[image]

Comment: Love it. Thanks for the tip!